# Circle CI Docker service does not cache COPY

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm running docker on [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) and I'm having trouble caching COPY commands.

The Circle CI docs mention [known caching issues](https://circleci.com/docs/docker#some-known-caching-issues) and recommend using [this perl script](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ExampleScripts#Setting_the_timestamps_of_the_files_to_the_commit_timestamp_of_the_commit_which_last_touched_them) to set the timestamps on the file copied over to preserve cache.

The [Docker best practice docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) state:

> In the case of the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the
>   file(s) being put into the image are examined. Specifically, a
>   checksum is done of the file(s) and then that checksum is used during
>   the cache lookup.

As per the CircleCi recommendations, I am saving the cache to disk then loading it again on the next test run. This seems to be working as commands prior to COPY cache correctly.

To debug, I'm outputting the md5 checksum of the file I am trying to copy locally, then from the docker container and it matches correctly. So, in theory the cache should load. I am not sure Docker uses md5 as a checksum.

This is my current circle.yml:

machine:
  services:
    - docker

```
dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - "~/docker"
  pre:
    - mkdir -p ~/docker
  override:
    - docker info
    - if [[ -e ~/docker/image.tar ]]; then docker load -i ~/docker/image.tar; fi
    - docker images
    - docker build -t circles .

checkout:
  post:
    - ls -l
    - ./timestamp-set-to-git.pl
    - ls -l

test:
  override:
    - md5sum .bowerrc
    - docker run circles md5sum .bowerrc
    - docker save circles > ~/docker/image.tar
```

This is what the build outputs for the checksum steps:

```
$md5sum .bowerrc
8d1a712721d735bd41bf738cae3226a2 .bowerrc

$docker run circles md5sum .bowerrc
8d1a712721d735bd41bf738cae3226a2 .bowerrc
```

But the `docker build` reports this:

```
Step 6 : RUN sudo npm install -g phantomjs gulp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a7bbf2b17977
Step 7 : COPY .bowerrc /var/work/.bowerrc
 ---> 7ad82336de64
```

Does anyone know why COPY is not caching?

Comment: Hi Rimian, i hit the same problem and searching for the solution. When i build my Docker container i want to copy files from my GIT repro inside the container with the COPY command. Sometimes it's working, sometimes not. Let me know when you found the solution.

Comment: The steps before COPY are cached by docker, since it then effectively only does a hash on the string after RUN <something>

Answer (score 5):

Docker uses a TARSUM to decide whether to use the Cache, and this includes file metadata.  Modified time most importantly... running a git clone will force it to rebuild from scratch.

To work around this, I use a Makefile with the following target...

```
build: hack-touch
    docker build -t MYTAG .
hack-touch:
    @echo "Reset timestamps on git working directory files..."
    find conf | xargs touch -t 200001010000.00
    touch -t 200001010000.00 Gruntfile.js bower.json package.json .bowerrc
```

(In my case, everything that I want to be cached like requirements.txt files are in conf except for the Gruntfile stuff on the second line.  None of my actual source code I want to be cached)

Comment: File modification and access timestamp metadata no longer affect caching. See my answer with link to docs. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073724/952932)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem using drone.io (another CI tool).

The reason why this happens is that 'git clone' will (over)write all local files, which will then also get the timestamp of the time of that clone. Since Docker takes the hash of all files added in a COPY or ADD command, this hash is now different from the one before. Docker then invalidates that cache and redoes that step and those after.