# Why is the COPY instruction causing a cache miss in my Docker build

Tags: docker, travis-ci

The [copy instruction](https://github.com/travitch/taffybar/blob/0392685bcc3622b48c8afbffbf148f7f697f7f1e/Dockerfile#L21) in the docker file for my project seems to cause a [cache miss](https://travis-ci.org/travitch/taffybar/jobs/368916195#L477), even though none of the files being copied have changed since the image was last pushed to docker hub. This causes all subsequent layers to miss the cache which makes the build take much longer than it should. I've also noticed that the hashes belonging to each layer seem to be different than what they are when I `docker build` on my local machine. Could this be because of a docker version mismatch? What is going on here? How can I diagnose this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share Dockerfile or the COPY instruction ?

Comment: The github link seems bad (`%20https` isn't a valid protocol, and even changing it to `https` I get an error). In any case StackOverflow guidelines requires you to share the code that does not work **in the question itself** so that we can look at it.

Comment: Not sure how that 20% got in the copy instruction link. Fixed now.

Answer (score 13):

Check the layers of the different images being built with `docker history --no-trunc $image`. On the copy step, you'll see a "file:abc" hash of the files being copied:

```
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                                        SIZE                COMMENT
sha256:202cb043f70a2565ea40629e891642e1e24be7b52e29116a6520736f47183904   9 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:d523f0d1cac93e44179baf9c36a7a4feff221b604224e26900075ddb02812448 in /test/test.txt    12B
```

If that hash is different between the two images you are building, then that will invalidate the build cache and result in the miss. Keep in mind the metadata of the files can also cause a cache miss, especially the file permissions. If you're still having problems, then please update the question to include the `docker history --no-trunc ...` output from the different builds.

Answer (score 5):

If the contents of your file have indeed not changed, differences in *permissions* can cause cache invalidation.

> For the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the file(s) in the image are examined and a checksum is calculated for each file. The last-modified and last-accessed times of the file(s) are not considered in these checksums. During the cache lookup, the checksum is compared against the checksum in the existing images. If anything has changed in the file(s), such as the contents and metadata, then the cache is invalidated.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/#leverage-build-cache

#### EDIT

As of Docker 20.10 a `--chmod` parameter [has been added](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34819) to `COPY` and `ADD` if you're using BuildKit (not in [the docs.](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md) yet, unfortunately). So you can ensure consistent permissions in your images and avoid permissions-related cache misses with e.g.

`COPY --chmod=<4-byte octal mask> ...`

Comment: Currently this happens in GitLab CI because of a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1736) that causes the source to be cloned with 666 permissions.

Answer (score 4):

As I've discussed in [this blog post](https://www.augmentedmind.de/2023/01/08/docker-build-cache-debug/), I found the following reasons for (unexpected) cache misses in Docker:

- If the problem happens in a *CI pipeline*, and if you use *multiple* build agent machines (or "ephemeral" machines), it might happen that build job #1 was executed on agent #A, but build job #2 was executed on agent #B, which has a different local cache than agent #A. Consequently, when you look at your CI pipeline output, be sure to check on which agent the jobs are executed. To prevent these kinds of cache misses, you can use a remote cache, storing caching information in a remote image registry. There are two implementation approaches: *inline* caching (where the image builder embeds caching meta-data into the image it builds), or using a separate *registry cache* (where a separate image is pushed that contains only cache blobs). The usage details of remote caching depend on your image builder tool. For instance, `docker build` supports only inline caching (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-external-cache-sources)), `docker buildx` (or when using BuildKit directly) supports both approaches (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/)), Buildah and kaniko only support the registry cache.
- If you use `ARG` in your Dockerfile, it is easy to accidentally break the cache invalidation. Whenever the value of some `ARG` is different between two `docker build` executions, the second execution won’t be able to reuse the previously cached layer for a `RUN` or `ENV` command that **uses** the `ARG`'s value. This then also invalidates all follow-up layers. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching) for background information. If you use *multi-stage builds*, and if you run `docker build` *several* times (for different *targets*), make sure you **always** provide the same *ARG* values to *all* docker build calls!
- Sometimes the entire image is rebuilt whenever a new **base** image has been released (that you reference in a `FROM` statement). This particularly happens if you use `docker build --pull`. You need to closely look at the builder’s output of the *first* layer, which includes the SHA-256 checksum of the base image. If it keeps changing frequently, there is no real "fix". Your image *should* be rebuilt, to include the most recent security fixes of the base image. However, if the base image is rebuilt *very often* (e.g. multiple times per day), you may want to stop using the `--pull` flag, and instead have a different approach that only runs `docker pull <base image>` (or *delete* the base image) more rarely, e.g. once per day.
- Layers for `COPY` or `ADD` statements are rebuilt "unexpectedly" whenever files change that you did not have on your radar (which you did not include into your `.dockerignore` yet). This could be the `.git` folder, or files created during building/testing (e.g. unit test report files, or log files). This typically happens when running `COPY . .`, because then your entire project directory is copied from the build context into the build container, which increases the chance that you missed excluding some superfluous files (that do not belong into the container anyway) via `.dockerignore`. To make it easy to address this issue, I developed a small CLI tool called [Directory Checksum](https://github.com/MShekow/directory-checksum/). It recursively computes the checksum of the contents of a directory, and prints the checksums up to a depth you can specify.